# How do I set up IntelliJ on dual monitors?

Tags: intellij-idea, multiple-monitors

I have just installed IntelliJ 9.0.2 on a machine running 64-bit Ubuntu 10.04.

How do I get another window to put on my second screen?

I would like to have both an editor and some tool windows on both screens.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

IntelliJ 14 and onwards you can select the settings cog and tick floating mode to detach menus, or drag editor tabs off the main window to detach them

If you're running on OSX you'll need to make sure it's not treating the screens as separate spaces, otherwise they'll snap back onto the same window as the main editor when switching between windows.

To do this untick **Displays have separate Spaces** in the **Mission Control** System Preferences.

Comment: Untick *Displays have separate Spaces* was the solution to avoid bouncing windows

Comment: when I have this one the screen on the second monitor goes black?

Comment: when you maximise (generally the green circle on the 10.10+) and application it will make any area not taken up by that application black. This can be avoided by instead using `option (alt) + green circle` to maximise the window

Answer (score 53):

All 'windows' inside of IntelliJ other than the code editor tabs have a "Float" option which pops open an independent window which you can drag to anywhere on your screen. This will allow you to manage your IDEA windows however you like.

IntelliJ also allow you to open multiple projects at once. When opening a project with one already opened, you are prompted as to wether you would like it in your current window or a "New Instance". If you choose new instance, it will open up a completely new IntelliJ with the other project in it. This will work for you if you have many projects you work on at once.

Comment: The part above about editor tabs not being 'floatable' is not even true anymore since IntelliJ 10. You can drag and drop editor tabs to be independent windows now too, as mentioned in rlovtang's answer.

Comment: Yeah but don't remember their place after a restart. So every time you have to setup them again

Comment: These new windows like to snap back to the original monitor on OS X, making multi-monitor setups annoying :/

Comment: @Supuhstar yeah, I'm just noticing the same. don't remember it happening on Yosemite though....

Comment: @muttonUp I'm on Yosemite and waiting for IT to give the go-ahead before upgrading to El Capitan.

Comment: @Supuhstar and muttonUp - Kerry M-R's answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/35616634/1019307) gives the answer to the issue on OSX.

Answer (score 13):

IntelliJ 10 will have [draggable & dockable editor tabs](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/11/intellij-idea-10-eap-98311/). A very nice feature. It's already present in the [early access versions](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+X+EAP).