# Intellij IDEA multiply windows project explorer

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

Could somebody tell me if it is possibile to open two instances of the same project in Intellj IDEA or can I for example have two windows with opened different project files with attached project explorer.

I asking for that because I have two monitors and it will be more efficient to navigate on each windows separately.

For now I must drag tab from root window and drop to another window which it is annoying and unhandy.

Comment: Please check out the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232204/how-do-i-set-up-intellij-on-dual-monitors

Comment: Thanks for quick response but could you read my question with more attention. I wrote that I use drag and drop technique and I don't have  more than one project.

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible. IntelliJ IDEA has a one project one window paradigm.

Some suggestions, in order of best to worst, that may help:

1. The navigation bar (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> or <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⇱</kbd> {Option Home}) can be used in place of the project tool window. You can use it either in pop-up mode or anchored mode (*View > Navigation Bar*). When a file is opened via the navigation bar, it opens in the window that has focus. The nav bar is ultimately a horizontal project window. Check the help documents for how to easily navigate through the nav bar. Once you get use to it, you may find you never use the project tool window again.
2. Have you tried floating the project window and placing it on the edge of one of the monitors so it sites between the two editor windows? While you would still need to drag file to the second editor window, it might prove easier.
3. You *could* create a second project with the all the same modules as the first project (just being sure to save the second project's .idea configuration directory in a different location). But this would require keeping two project configurations in sync, and you would need to make sure the "synchronize files on frame activation" setting is on. In the end, I think that is far more hassle then it is worth.

Hope that helps.
(FYI, I may be new to StackOverflow, but I'm a ten year passionate and evangelical IntelliJ IDEA user.)

Comment: As someone who works in an organisation which is very anal on their package names and layout, I really hope they'd add this feature in the future...

Comment: @EvilWashingMachine you reminded me that I have clothes in the dryer - thanks friend!

Comment: @RonDahlgren too late, I have already shrunk your favourite sweater 2 sizes and now my door refuses to open for no reason and I have no mechanical override...muahahaha